# How to Set the Document Information Panel to "Show Always" in Content Type Settings in SP 2013 using Powershell!

Tags: powershell, content-type

I am trying to set the Site Settings> COntent TYpes > Content Type Settings> Document Information Panel to "Show Always" Using POwerShell.

I used the following code:

$ct = $spweb.ContentTypes["ZNA Document"]
$enable = $ct.xmldocuments.replace('False', 'True')
$OldSchema = 
$ct.xmlDocuments.Delete($OldSchema)
$ct.xmlDocuents.Add($enable)
$ct.Update()

But this doesnt seem to work.

Any Help is appreciated.

Cheers